# permanently stop iPhone text messages from appearing on my iMac

Tags: messages

How do I permanently stop iPhone text messages from appearing on my iMac. I don't want to send/receive/view messages on my computer. I only want to use my phone for sending/receiving/viewing messages. Also, I'm hoping the fix doesn't require constant maintenance. I've gotten advice for this before, but the fix has to be repeated every time I restart my computer.

Answer (score 6):

To disable Text Message Forwarding:

1. On your iPhone, open the Settings app, then tap on Messages, then Text Message Forwarding.
2. Tap on the on/off button across from your Mac's name to disable.

Comment: I find it disturbing to see that in my case this option is not selected, and never had been, and that if I had it was *supposed* to be something I would've approved with a passcode. Lovely...

Comment: This answer is specifically regarding SMS forwarding. IMessages are always sent to both places, assuming you are signed into the same Apple ID on each device/computer.

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically mean iMessage, rather than SMS forwarding, then ...

- Launch Messages on the Mac
- Messages menu > Preferences > Accounts > [Settings] > Sign out

Comment: Thank you for the informaton but the "Preference" tab is located under the "Message" heading & not the "File" heading.

Comment: oops, so it is. Fixed.

Comment: I find it disturbing that the top answer suggests the opposite, which is that it requires something be initiated from the iPhone requiring a passcode. But all I had to do was use the same apple ID and it's already doing it, and I have to disable it from the macbook indeed. So it's intercepting SMS from my cell carrier on systems I didn't specifically approve for doing that. And the phone itself indicates that it would not allow such a thing. Lovely

Comment: tubedogg's answer is specifically for SMS, mine is for iMessage - they are 2 different things. Lots of info at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681