# Is it possible to receive text messages on my iPhone and Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, messages, continuity

Is it possible to receive text messages on both my iPhone and my Mac? Just got Mac for the first time. I don't carry it around with me but have missed some important text messages recently as they are going directly to the Mac and not to my iPhone.  I'm not sure what to do. It would be great if I could receive text message  on my iPhone and my Mac. If this isn't possible, I prefer to only receive text messages on my iPhone.

Comment: Essentially, what you want is not possible - your 'fix' is at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156115/permanently-stop-iphone-text-messages-from-appearing-on-my-imac?rq=1 & some very clever, but ultimately unsuccessful attempts to work around it can be seen at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/how-to-tell-messages-im-not-at-home

Comment: In short, a message is considered 'successfully delivered' if **any** signed-in device picks it up.

Comment: I find this question unclear, haven't flagged yet though as @tetsujin seems to understand it. I receive both iMessages and SMS successfully on all my Apple devices and they're all synced. Are both devices sending from and receiving from your phone number and are both fully updated?

Comment: Agree with @JBallin... Seems like the only way for a message to arrive at the Mac but not the iPhone is if the message is an iMessage, not a SMS, addressed to a phone number or email that the iPhone has been set not to check. Susan, does your iPhone have all of its [iMessage "You can be reached at" options](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349) checked?

Comment: Okay, two ways--it took me a little bit to understand @tetsujin's edge case. Still, AFAIK the SMS relay feature depends on the iPhone to pass the message on to other iCloud devices, so only iMessages would be able to show up on the Mac first (and I'm surprised that they don't show up on the iPhone as unread messages once it reconnects to a data-capable network.)

Comment: Based on @Tetsujin's links my only theory is that you aren't letting your mac sleep and that you sometimes don't have your phone connected to internet/cellular and in those cases I suppose it's possible the phone never receives those messages? In that case why don't you just set your computer to go to sleep after a certain amount of time of not using?